# Ansible lineinfile regexp to manage /etc/exports

Tags: regex, ansible

I've been hitting a wall trying to get /etc/exports managed via Ansible.

I've got a role that installs a piece of software on a VM, and I want to then add an entry ot /etc/exports on the NFS server, for that specific VM, so it's able to access the NFS shares needed.

Lineinfile sounds like the way to go, but sofar I can't figure out how to properly write this.

I want this to:

- not modify if the host is in the line, no matter where
- add the NFS share and the host if there's no line for the NFS share
- add the host to the share in case it isn't in there.

The latest installment of my 'add to /etc/exports' that thought should work, but doesn't, is:

```
- name: Add hosts to mountpoint line
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/exports
    line: '\1 {{ host_ip }}(root_squash,no_subtree_check)'
    regex: '^((?!{{ volume_mountpoint }}.*{{ host_ip }}\(root_squash,no_subtree_check\).*).*)$'
    backrefs: yes
```

but i'm still getting all kinds of weird side effects. I've used backreferences etc before, but somehow this one keeps tripping me up.

Anyone who sees what's gong wrong?

Typical /etc/exports entry:

```
/srv/files    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to combine two actions into one -- whether a host is present in the exports, and whether it needs to be added. That's not even covering the case where a host is present but shouldn't be -- do you have total control over the contents, meaning you could just write it out completely each time, knowing all hosts that should be in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in one step to modify a line using backreferences or add the line if missing. To modify the existing mount point the back-references are needed. For example, given the files for testing

```sh
shell> cat etc/export1
/srv/files    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

shell> cat etc/export2
/srv/files    172.16.0.15(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

shell> cat etc/export3
/srv/download    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

the task

```yaml
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: "etc/{{ item }}"
        regex: '^{{ mount }}(\s+)({{ ipr }})*({{ optionsr }})*(\s*)(.*)$'
        line: '{{ mount }}\g<1>{{ ip }}{{ options }} \g<5>'
        backrefs: true
      vars:
        mount: /srv/files
        ipr: '172\.16\.0\.14'
        ip: '172.16.0.14'
        optionsr: '\(.*?\)'
        options: '(root_squash,no_subtree_check)'
      loop:
        - export1
        - export2
        - export3
```

gives

```yaml
--- before: etc/export1 (content)
+++ after: etc/export1 (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-/srv/files    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
+/srv/files    172.16.0.14(root_squash,no_subtree_check) 

changed: [localhost] => (item=export1)
```

```yaml
--- before: etc/export2 (content)
+++ after: etc/export2 (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-/srv/files    172.16.0.15(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
+/srv/files    172.16.0.14(root_squash,no_subtree_check) 172.16.0.15(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

changed: [localhost] => (item=export2)
```

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=export3)
```

The first two files are all right. The problem is the third file. The line hasn't been added to the file. Quoting from [backrefs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs)

> *"... if the regexp does not match anywhere in the file, the file will be left unchanged."*

The explanation is simple. There are no groups if the *regex* doesn't match. If there are no groups the *line* can't be created.

On the other hand, quoting from [regexp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp)

> "*... If the regular expression is not matched, the line will be added to the file ...*"

As a result, it's not possible to ask *lineinfile* to add a line if the *regexp* does not match and, at the same time, to do nothing if the *regexp* is matched. If the *regexp* is matched you need back-references. If you use back-references you can't add a missing line.

To solve this problem read the content of the files and create a dictionary

```yaml
    - command: "cat etc/{{ item }}"
      register: result
      loop: [export1, export2, export3]
    - set_fact:
        content: "{{ dict(_files|zip(_lines)) }}"
      vars:
        _lines: "{{ result.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
        _files: "{{ result.results|map(attribute='item')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  content:
    export1:
    - /srv/files    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
    export2:
    - /srv/files    172.16.0.15(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
    export3:
    - /srv/download    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Now add the line only if missing, i.e. do not replace the line if the mount point is already there

```yaml
   - lineinfile:
        path: "etc/{{ item }}"
        line: '{{ mount }} {{ ip }}{{ options }}'
      vars:
        mount: /srv/files
        ip: '172.16.0.14'
        options: '(root_squash,no_subtree_check)'
      loop: "{{ content|list }}"
      when: content[item]|select('search', mount)|length == 0
```

gives

```yaml
skipping: [localhost] => (item=export1) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=export2) 
--- before: etc/export3 (content)
+++ after: etc/export3 (content)
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 /srv/download    172.16.0.14(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
+/srv/files 172.16.0.14(root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't thought of doing it this way... every day we learn :)

Comment: Further testing shows that this is not idempotent though - when running with another host, the entries end up being duplicated:

/share hostA(rw) hostB(rw) hostA(rw)

Comment: Open new question and present the not idempotent case in [mre].

Comment: Posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701046/ansible-lineinfile-re-adding-items

Comment: I've read the question. I'm not going to answer it. Make sure you understand what minimal, complete, and reproducible means. Do not proceed here unless you have [relevant comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Comment: I've created a decent minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874960/ansible-line-in-file-re-adding-entries